# Concise Way to Say "Small Tasks can be as Important as Big Tasks"

Tags: word-choice, phrases, phrase-requests, expression-choice

I need a concise way to explain this idea:

> Doing the small and easy tasks can be as noble (or more worthwhile) than doing the hard tasks.

Examples:

- 100 people can be more effective by working on small tasks — like creating community gardens all over the city, reducing carbon in the environment — than working on larger ones like experimenting and failing at curing major diseases.
- I'm more effective spending an hour doing something I know well instead of doing heart surgery.

Going on this train of thought, I imagine there is a word to describe a phase of creating art, brainstorming, or constructing a house that is more productive than others.

As you can see, I'm struggling with a high-level comparison of productivity and effectiveness in *individuals* versus those in *a collective*. And also the process someone goes through to say: “Am I going to forge a new road alone (like a cowboy) or join a collective effort?”

I'm trying to avoid politically-charged words like *sharing economy*, *collective*, and *communism*.

Comment: Thousands of them. Consider the classical author Ovid, who said _Adde parvum parvo, magnus acervus erit_, that is, "Add little to little, [and there] will be [a] big heap".

Comment: Your best bet might be to search for lists of "famous quotations" or "aphorisms". Perhaps under the topics of work, effort, or accomplishment. Bring back a few, and we'll help you decide if they're fitted to your purpose.

Comment: For want of a nail ...

Answer (score 1):

> "many hands make light work"

This expression talks about collective effort being more effective than individual effort.